# R Shiny - add tabPanel to tabsetPanel dynamically (with the use of renderUI)

Tags: r, tabpanel, shiny

I am developing a shiny application in which I use `tabsetPanel`, which is generated when user enters some particular input. Thus, I want to use `renderUI` function to make a tabsetPanel appear / disappear.

My struggle now is that **number of** `tabPanel` elements (arguments of `tabsetPanel`) **also depends on user input**, in the way: sometimes I need 1 one, other times I want more `tabPanels`.

How to make it? I tried including `conditionPanel` or including simple `if()...` condition in the `tabsetPanel` argument, but it (rather not surprisingly...) did not work.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Here you go. The code is fairly self explanatory.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')  
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$mytabs = renderUI({
      nTabs = input$nTabs
      myTabs = lapply(paste('Tab', 1: nTabs), tabPanel)
      do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you have any questions on the code itself, post here.

Comment: Add on: Once you have the added tabs, what is the proper way to add the same `uiOutput` to all tabs, but make the values unique within each tab? Or is this different?

If you add an `output$base_tab_ui` and render them in each, all of them hold the same `input$value` for each tab.  Is there a way to make these unique with different input variable names?

Comment: @Ramnath how would you go about populating each of these dynamic tabs with its own content? perhaps, say, a renderTable / tableOutput of a data.frame which can be filtered using the same object I used to populate the tab names (ie `nTabs = length(lags_7)` and `myTabs = lapply(sprintf('%s', lags_7), tabPanel)`) (possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276104/r-shiny-how-to-add-data-tables-to-dynamically-created-tabs)

Comment: @d8aninja, assuming that you have some plots added to a list called myPlots, you can do: `nTabs = length(myPlots); myTabs = lapply(1:nTabs, function(x){tabPanel(paste0("Tab ",x), renderPlot(myPlots[[x]]))}); do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)`

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to dynamically add tabPanels **without** renderUI, which might not be as obvious as the version with renderUI. I wrote a function **addTabToTabset** which will append any (list of) tabPanel(s) to a tabset/navbar.

This approach has a set of **advantages** over using renderUI:

- Existing tabPanels are not re-rendered each time a new panel is added. (faster)
- Thus, not resetting all the input variables inside existing Panels. (no variable storing workarounds needed)
- Structure of the panel contents can be chosen individually. (In the lapply - renderUI version, all panels have to be somewhat uniform.)

The solution and code sample can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020810/dynamically-creating-tabs-with-plots-in-shiny-without-re-creating-existing-tabs/). If requested, I could also post the code here.