# Render dynamic number of charts in shiny based on multiple selectInput selections

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a simple test app using mtcars data that contains a loop to generate a dynamic number of charts based on input selections. I have adapted guidance in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686773/shiny-dynamic-number-of-output-elements-plots) but the app is rendering the same exact data for each of the charts. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
library(googleVis)

mtcars$Car.Name <- row.names(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(            
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),            
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "chooseVar",
                label = "Choose Cut Variable:",
                choices = colnames(mtcars)[-length(colnames(mtcars))],
                multiple = T),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "chooseCar",
                label = "Choose Car :",
                choices = row.names(mtcars),
                multiple = T)
  ),            
  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  varList <- reactive(input$chooseVar )
  
  
  #dynamically create the right number of htmlOutput
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(varList() , function(i) {
      plotname <- paste0("plot_", i)
      htmlOutput(plotname)
      
    })
    
    tagList(plot_output_list)
  }) 
  
  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page. 
  
  for (i in colnames(mtcars)[-length(colnames(mtcars))]) {  
    
    local({
      my_i <- i
      
      plotname <- paste0("plot_", my_i)
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderGvis({
        data <- mtcars[which(row.names(mtcars) %in% input$chooseCar),]
        if(dim(data)[1]>0){
          gvisColumnChart(    
            data, xvar='Car.Name', yvar= i 
          )}
        else NULL
      })  
    })
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try with `gvisColumnChart(..., yvar = my_i)` instead of `yvar = i`

Comment: That did it, thanks!