# Dynamic navbarMenu tabPanels in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a navbarMenu with a set of tabPanels that works fine (code block 1 below) but I want to make this dynamic so that I can add or remove tabPanels based on a condition *at startup*. Something along the lines of what I have in block 2 below (but that doesn't work). I'm seeing a couple of links to where people say this is not possible but it seems there must be a way. I actually only need to include or not include tabPanels on start up and don't need it to be truly dynamic.

I see an example that is close with a tabsetPanel : [R Shiny - add tabPanel to tabsetPanel dynamically (with the use of renderUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamicaly-with-the-use-of-renderui). And here it says it's not possible: [reactive tabPanel in a navbarMenu in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544100/reactive-tabpanel-in-a-navbarmenu-in-shiny)

**Block 1: works but not dynamic**

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(

    tabPanel("a"

    ),
    tabPanel("b"),
    navbarMenu('g', 
                 tabPanel("c"),
                 tabPanel("d")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){


  }
))
```

**Block 2: I want something like this - this doesn't work**

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(

    tabPanel("a"

    ),
    tabPanel("b"),
    navbarMenu('g', 
                 uiOutput('tabs')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){

    output$tabs <- renderUI({

      listoftabs <- c("c", "d")
      lapply(listoftabs, tabPanel)

    })
  }
))
```

[reactive tabPanel in a navbarMenu in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544100/reactive-tabpanel-in-a-navbarmenu-in-shiny)

Comment: You need to put `narbarMenu` inside your `renderUI`. You cannot simply add `tabPanel` to an existing `navbarMenu` or `tabsetPanel` (the example that works has `tabsetPanel` inside `renderUI`).

Comment: Have you tested this out? I've tested many different variations of this and none seem to work. Does navbarMenu work at all from within a renderUI?

Comment: Sorry `navbarMenu` wouldn't work. The reason is that `navbarMenu` is part of the `navbarPage`. When you put `navbarMenu` inside `navbarPage`, it generates two HTML elements: one for the menu link, the other for the actual panel `div`. When you use it with `renderUI`, you only get the panel `div`. If you want dynamics, you'll have to re-render the whole `navbarPage`

Comment: Re-rendering would not be good. Since this only matters on start up, I only need a mechanism at start up that basically says if(something) then include both tabPanel c and d, otherwise include just c.

Comment: If this condition is not user-entered, you can add `if/else` to your ui code to determine which elements show up.     `navbarMenu('g', 
               if (a == 1) {
                 tabPanel("c")
               } else if (a == 2) {
                 tabPanel("d")
               }
    )`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @warmoverflow (thanks!) with ifelse could work with a very limited number of tabs but if the tab you want included or excluded is a middle tab it won't work properly given the commas. Here is a solution where I rewrote the `navbarMenu` function just slightly to allow you to drop a tab meeting a condition

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(

    tabPanel("a"

    ),
    tabPanel("b"),
    f('g', drop = ifelse(1==1, 2, 3), 
               tabPanel("first"),
               tabPanel("firstinside"),
               tabPanel("secondinside"),
               tabPanel("last")
      )
),
  server = function(input, output, session){


  }
))



f <- function (title, drop , ..., icon = NULL) 
{
    structure(list(title = title, tabs = list(...)[-drop], iconClass = shiny:::iconClass(icon)), 
        class = "shiny.navbarmenu")
}
```