# Dynamic tabs and checkbox group in R shiny with renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a dynamic UI in which some `tabPanel` and `checkboxGroup` are created dynamically depending on the data.

Below an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Group" = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"),
  "Name" = c("Bob", "Paul", "Peter", "Emma", "John"),
  "Value" = seq(1,10, length.out=5),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df
    Group   Name  Value
1 Group A    Bob   1.00
2 Group B   Paul   3.25
3 Group A  Peter   5.50
4 Group A   Emma   7.75
5 Group B   Jhon  10.00
```

I managed to create two `tabPanel` called "Group A" and "Group B" according to the unique values in column "Group" of my data frame. I can also create a `checkboxGroupInput` based on the unique values of column "Name" for each group.

However, I don't understand where to place the usual server block to output a table subsetted per Group and the values checked in the box. None of the similar discussions I saw can help with this particular situation.

See my attempt below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')
  )
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    Tabs_titles = unique(df$Group)

    do.call(tabsetPanel,
            lapply(Tabs_titles,
                    function(x){
                      tabPanel(title = x,
                               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkboxID",
                                                  label = "My Checkbox",
                                                  choices = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name),
                                                  selected = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name)
                               ),
                               DT::dataTableOutput("my_Table")
                      )
                    }
            )
    )
    })

  ### Where to place this 'usual' server code below? ###

  # Observe box values when changed
  box_values = reactive({input$checkboxID})

  # Output table
  output$my_Table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    subset(df, Group = <cannot catch the variable 'x' from above>, Name = box_values)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you can get some inspiration here: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html

Comment: The goal is to subset a data frame by first creating a tabPanel-based dynamic UI. I saw the page you mentioned, along [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamically-with-the-use-of-renderui), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276104/r-shiny-how-to-add-data-tables-to-dynamically-created-tabs) and other like [this one](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(
  "Group" = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"),
  "Name" = c("Bob", "Paul", "Peter", "Emma", "John"),
  "Value" = seq(1,10, length.out=5),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')
  )
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {

  Tabs_titles = unique(df$Group)

  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    myTabs <- lapply(Tabs_titles,
                    function(x){
                      tabPanel(title = x,
                               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = paste0("checkboxID_", x),
                                                  label = "My Checkbox",
                                                  choices = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name),
                                                  selected = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name)
                               ),
                               tableOutput(paste0("my_Table_", x))
                      )
                    }
    )

    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)

  })

  observe(
    lapply(Tabs_titles,
           function(x){
             checked_names <- reactive({input[[paste0("checkboxID_", x)]]})

             output[[paste0("my_Table_", x)]] <-renderTable({
               df %>%
               subset(Group == x & Name %in% checked_names())
             })
           }
    )
  )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making the problem more complicated than it needs to be, and as a result have created a couple of insoluble problems for yourself.  Your first problem is that you are creating several `checkboxGroupInput`s with the same ID.  This means that Shiny isn't going to be able to distinguish them from one another.  And, as you've discovered, neither can you!

As I understand it, you want to display the data from a subset of the people in your data.  The first filter is done by selecting the group in a `selectInput`.  Then the required names are selected using `checkboxGroupInput`.  The options available to the `checkboxGroupInput` depend on the group selected in the `selectInput`.

I think you can do all of that without having to resort to `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.  The key is the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` (which needs the additional argument `session` in the definition of your `server` function).  I think this does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Dynamic checkboxGroupInput"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("group", "Group", choices=c("Group A", "Group B")),
        checkboxGroupInput("name", "Name", choices=c())
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("data")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(
    "Group" = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"),
    "Name" = c("Bob", "Paul", "Peter", "Emma", "John"),
    "Value" = seq(1,10, length.out=5),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

  observeEvent(input$group, {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session, 
      "name",
      choices=df %>% subset(Group == input$group) %>% pull(Name),
      selected = df %>% subset(Group == input$group) %>% pull(Name)
    )
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({
    req(input$group, input$name)
    df %>% filter(Group == input$group, Name %in% input$name)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here I used a simple dataset for illustration purpose of a dynamic UI. I have to display `tabPanel`s based on values of a data frame column and not a `selectInput` menu, using a dynamic UI. But the finality of the app is the same as yours indeed (i.e. subsetting the original data frame). I just don't see how to link the output to the dynamic UI.

Comment: Ok.  Do you mean the `tabPanel`s displayed depend on the group selected, and each `tabPanel` needs to display a filtered dataset?  (That would explain the need for `uiOutput`!)  Is it the same filtering of the same dataset in each `tabPanel`?

Comment: Correct. `tabPanels` are created from a vector of unique values in the "Group" column, and the `checkboxGroupInput` choices from the unique "Group"-specific values of the 'Name' column. All that by using the same original data frame `df`, in order to obtain a table in each tab containing a subset of `df` per "Group" and per values selected in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *partial* solution, following on from your comment to my first suggestion.  The code below provides a dynamic `checkboxGroupInput` together with set of `tabPanel`s whose labels and number updates with changes to the `checkboxgroupInput`.  Unfortunately, I've not yet been able to put the filtered dataset on the `tabPanel`s.  As soon as I put *any* output on the `tabPanel`s, the `checkboxGroupInput` disappears.  Strangely, putting inputs on the `tabPanel` doesn't cause any problems.

I'm posting this partial solution in the hope that someone else can see what's wrong and provide you with a complete answer before I get the chance to look at it again.

My solution uses nested [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  I could probably get away without the nesting, but I think the nesting keeps the code clean.

The first module controls the `tabPanel`s.  It reacts to changes to `input$group` in the main server.  It updates the `checkboxgroupInput`'s choice list, creates a `tabPanel` and an instance of the data table module for each row in the filtered dataset.

Here's the code, more comments afterwards.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  "Group" = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"),
  "Name" = c("Bob", "Paul", "Peter", "Emma", "John"),
  "Value" = seq(1,10, length.out=5),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

# dataTable module definition
dataTableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS("id")

  paste0("Content for ", stringr::str_split(id, fixed("-"))[[1]][2])
}

dataTableController <- function(input, output, session, group, nameList) {
  ns <- session$ns

  rv <- reactive({
  })

  return(rv)
}

# tabPanel module definition
tabPanelsUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    checkboxGroupInput(ns("names"), label="Select names:", choices=c(), selected=c()),
    uiOutput(ns("tabPanel"))
  )
}

tabPanelsController <- function(input, output, session, selector) {
  ns <- session$ns

  output$tabPanel <- renderUI({
    req(v$filteredData)
    tabList <- lapply(v$filteredData$Name, function(x) tabPanel(title=x, dataTableUI(ns(x))))
    do.call(tabsetPanel, tabList)
  })

  v <- reactiveValues(
    filteredData=NA
  )

  observe({
    req(selector())
    v$filteredData <- df %>% subset(Group == selector())
    lapply(
      v$filteredData$Name, 
      function(x) {
        callModule(dataTableController, x, group=reactive({selector()}), nameList=reactive({input$names}))
      }
    )
  })

  observeEvent(v$filteredData, {
    nameList <- v$filteredData %>% pull(Name)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "names", choices=nameList, selected=nameList)
  })

  rv <- reactive({
  })

  return(rv)
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic checkboxGroupInput"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("group", "Group", choices=c("Group A", "Group B"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabPanelsUI("tabs")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selectedNames <- callModule(tabPanelsController, "tabs", reactive({input$group}))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will see that the data panel module simply prints out a static text:

```
dataTableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS("id")

  paste0("Content for ", stringr::str_split(id, fixed("-"))[[1]][2])
}
```

reflecting the name of the person to which the `tabPanel` relates.  It should be a simple matter to replace the static text with a datatable

```
dataTableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS("id")

  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("my_Table"))
}
```

and make the appropriate changes to the server function.  But when I do, the `checkboxGroupInput` disappears.  I can't figure out why.

Both the tabPanel and data table modules currently return `NULL`.  That means that

```
  rv <- reactive({
  })

  return(rv)
```

is strictly unnecessary in both cases, but I've put it there as a placeholder should your full solution need it.

The modularisation solves the problem of letting the main server function know which data table it needs to modify by removing the need for it to do so.  The module would handle all its own updates internally (once the data table is displayed!).  If the main server needs to know the *result* of the update (or anything else about what the module is doing, then the main server can monitor the module's return value.