# Add new tab using insertUI

Tags: r, shiny

[There are some solutions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamicaly-with-the-use-of-renderui) already about adding / removing tabs but I felt that with `insertUI` and `removeUI`, this should be hassle free. When I tried I found myself unable to figure out the id to specify in the command to even begin with. Help please?

In a nutshell, is it possible to add a new tab with insertUI/removeUI?

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Otherwise it is quite hard to answer the question. "hassle free" is really a matter of opinion.

Comment: In a nutshell, is it possible to add a new tab with insertUI/removeUI?

Comment: It's more difficult than it looks. When you call `tabsetPanel(tabPanel(...`, Shiny generates two HTML elements separately (the tab title inside `ul>li`, and the tab content inside a `div`). When you use `insertUI(tabPanel)`, it only generates the `div` elements, thus you'll need to figure out a way to insert the necessary title as well in a different HTML node.

Comment: @TheComeOnMan, Did you get an answer to above? I have a similar problem to solve. :D