# loop through a list to create a continuing html code by a customized fluidrow function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a customized function will create html using fluidrow() with different arguments. I have created a list that I want to pass to this customized function.

Here is the function

```
rawname = function(name){
  x = paste0(name, "_raw_ww_plot")
return(x)
}

w10 = function(name){
  x = paste0(name, "_10ws_plot")
  return(x)
}

w20 = function(name){
  x = paste0(name, "_20ws_plot")
  return(x)
}

listname = function(name){
  x = list(c(map_chr(name, w10), "Previous 10 Weeks"),
           c(map_chr(name, w20), "Previous 20 Weeks"),
           c(map_chr(name, rawname), "All Time"))
  return(x)
}

make.fluidrow = function(html, list, bar = hr(), col = 12, 
                         box.num = 2){
  htmlvar = sapply(html, function(x) {
    paste0("<div style='text-align:center'><h3>", 
           x,
           "</h3></div><br>")})
  
  if (box.num == 1){
    row = fluidRow(
      column(col,
             box(HTML(htmlvar[1]),
                 do.call(tabsetPanel, 
                         lapply(list, function(y){tabPanel(y[2], 
                                                           plotlyOutput(y[1], 
                                                                        height = "100%"),                                                            width = 6)}))),
             bar))
  } else if (box.num == 2)
    row = fluidRow(
      column(col,
             box(HTML(htmlvar[1]),
                 do.call(tabsetPanel, 
                         lapply(list, function(y){tabPanel(y[3], 
                                                           plotlyOutput(y[1], 
                                                                        height = "100%"), 
                                                           width = 6)}))),
             box(HTML(htmlvar[2]),
                 do.call(tabsetPanel, 
                         lapply(list, function(y){tabPanel(y[3], 
                                                           plotlyOutput(y[2], 
                                                                        height = "100%"), 
                                                           width = 6)}))),
             bar))
  return(row)  
}
```

here is the list

```
a1 = list(c("San Francisco Public Utilities Commission (SFPUC) Oceanside",
               "San Francisco Public Utilities Commission (SFPUC) Southeast"),
             listname(c("SFOcean", "SFPUC_SE")))

a2 = list(c("East Bay Municpal Utility District (EBMUD)",
                "Central Contra Costa Sanitation District (CCCSD)"),
              listname(c("EBMUD", "CCCSD")))
a3 = list(c("Silicon Valley Clean Water",
                "Palo Alto Regional Water Quality Control Plant"),
              listname(c("SVCW", "PA")))
alist = list(a1, a2, a3)
```

Inside the tabPanel(), I am trying to loop through the alist and create an output that is equal to the output from the follow codes

```
make.fluidrow(html = a1[[1]], list = a1[[2]][3], bar = br()),
make.fluidrow(html = a2[[1]], list = a2[[2]][3], bar = br()),
make.fluidrow(html = a3[[1]], list = a3[[2]][3], bar = br()))
```

I have tried this following code but it creates a list of html code instead of the continuous html code that will be created by the code just about this one

```
map(alist,  ~make.fluidrow(html = .[[1]], list = .[[2]][3], bar = br()))
```

And I have read online and saying do.call can make the continuous html code. I have tried the following code but it gave an errors saying "Error in do.call(make.fluidrow, c(alist, list(html = .[[1]], list = .[[2]][3],  : object '.' not found". I just don't know how to pass the arguments refer to the alist like code that I used map function

```
do.call(make.fluidrow, c(alist, list(html = .[[1]], list = .[[2]][3], bar = br())))
```

how can I write a code that will loop through the each item in alist and create a continuous html codes. Also, would like to know if the arguments can refer to the list in the do.call function and if so, how to do it.

Comment: You can't return a collection of things that's not in a list from an R function so `do.call` isn't going to help you. Maybe this existing question will do what you want already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamically-with-the-use-of-renderui The `listname` function is not defined so we can't run the code you provided. Maybe you want `do.call("tabsetPanel", map(alist,  ~make.fluidrow(html = .[[1]], list = .[[2]][3], bar = br())))`

Comment: @MrFlick my bad. Addedthe additional functions in order to run the make.fluidrow(). Your suggestion is good and I will give it a try. I want to ask if there is absolutely no way to covert a list of html code to a continuous html code?